# What is an alternative to using split() on a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, meta-tags

I have content in a meta tag.

```
<meta property="video" content="initialver=1.0" />
```

I get the content in this tag using `getAttribute("content")`. Then I have a string: `initialver=1.0`. My need is getting "1.0". How can I do this without using `split()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = "initialver=1.0";
var result = str.substring(11);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to do this

```
var x = "initialver=1.0".match(/\d+$|\d+\.\d+$/)[0]
```